# IBM Bluemix suports Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ibm-cloud

The plataform **Bluemix** from IBM has support for **Primefaces**?

I deployed a app in **JSF + Primefaces** and Primefaces components did not show up. On the other hand, the JSF components appeared.

I did the same test with the application running in **apache tomcat 8**, in which case there were no problems.

Comment: "Don't appear" is way to vague. I hope you can, as a developer, investigate way more. And also read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I just wonder if the bluemix supports Primefaces.

Comment: I answered your question but I'm 100% sure it does not help you. You, still need to answer my other comment to get anywhere

Answer (score 1):

My [google results](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-deploy-jsf-application-on-bluemix.html) say it is possible to run jsf on bluemix, so the answer is YES

Comment: I knew that jsf ran in bluemix . My doubt it was the Primefaces .

Looking at my question, I really have not explained well . I will provide more details .

Comment: You don't have to 'explain' better, you have to **investigate** better as a developer, not an end-user. https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+not+displayed

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice.